# Files in the SD card are disappeared

Tags: java, android, qr-code

now i am using :
 String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
 File QRCode = new File(dir + File.separator + "QRCode.txt");

the records on the QRCode.txt file are erased after a few days/hours . i dont know why.
  what can be the reason for that ?how can i protect my records so that they wont be erased from the file QRCode.txt ?

Comment: Tal - Any update? Did the solution work for you?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more information and I hope, you should be able to get rid of the issue now. Feel free to comment in case of any further issue/doubt.

Comment: when i used  File QRCode = new File("/sdcard/QRCode.txt"); instead of  String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
           File QRCode = new File(dir + File.separator + "QRCode.txt");  Is that the reason that caused the all data of the QRCode.txt to be disappeared ?

Comment: No, that's not the reason. The reason for the content to get disappeared is not opening the file in append mode as I've mentioned in the update. Did the updated solution work for you?

Comment: i still have a problem when i use the append mode : FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(QRCode, true); instead of FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(QRCode); the record is being created a lot of times instead of one time only . i need that the record to be created only one time and not many times.  what should i do ?

Comment: It all depends on how you are processing the file. Append mode is required when you just want to append something to the end. However, if you want to just change something, you should not open the file in append mode.

Comment: i just want to change a record so i dont need to open the file in append mode .my problem is that when i used my first code with File QRCode = new File("/sdcard/QRCode.txt") the data of the file QRCode.txt was erased after a few days/weeks(all the records were erased from the file QRCode) . now i am using string dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); File QRCode = new File(dir + File.separator +"/sdcard/QRCode.txt"); my queustion is , what was the reason that my data was erased ? will it be erased now also ?

Comment: Is it sure that the records from the file QRCode wont be erased ?  (once i use  string dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); File QRCode = new File(dir + File.separator +"/sdcard/QRCode.txt");  )

Comment: the records on the file QRCode are still erased after a few days .  what can be the reason that they are erased from the file ?

Comment: the records are still erased . what can be the reason for that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path to the directory as follows:

```
String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

Then, you need to add the path of the file (including its name) to `dir` in order to create the full path of the file e.g.

```
File QRCode = new File(dir + File.separator + path-to-your-file-on-SD-card);
```

e.g.

```
File QRCode = new File(dir + File.separator + QRCode.txt);
```

Also, make sure to open the file in **append** mode when you are opening it to append something to it e.g. if you are using [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)), in order to open it in **append** mode, you will have to pass `true` to its constructor as shown below:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(QRCode, true);
```

However, if you want to change something in the file, you must not open the file in append mode. Rather, you must open it with the following constructor (or with passing `false` to the constructor mentioned above), read the content into some variable(s), process and change the content as per the requirement, and write the changed content back to the file.

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(QRCode);
```

**Side Note:** Always follow the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. `QRCode` should be named as `qrCode`.

Comment: now i am using : String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); File QRCode = new File(dir + File.separator + "QRCode.txt");

the records on the QRCode.txt file are erased after a few days/hours . i dont know why. what can be the reason for that ?how can i protect my records so that they wont be erased from the file QRCode.txt ?

Comment: @tal - None of the ways you have used so far is the reason behind it. There is something else (e.g. some background job or virus or something which you will be able to know after thorough analysis).

Comment: can i write the files to my screen memory instead of the sd card ?  i mean can i write QRCode.txt to another place in the memory that isnt the sd card ?